# Проблема с кодом С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы после использования калькулятора я смог в консоль ввести exit и закрыть, тем самым, консоль. Данный код не компилируется, написано, что есть ошибка в последней фигурной скобки, требуется while, но я не понимаю как его ввести

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    string o;

    do
    {
        cout << "Выполните действие" << endl;
        float x, y, z;
        char q;
        cin >> x;
        cin >> q;
        cin >> y;
        {
            switch (q)
            {
                case '^':
                    z = pow(x, y);

                case '+':
                    (z = x + y);

                case '-':
                    (z = x - y);

                case '/':
                    (z = x / y);

                case '*':
                    (z = x * y);
            }
        }
        cout << (z) << endl;
        cin >> o;

        if (o == "exit")
            exit(0);
        else
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В С++ нет конструкции `do {...}`, есть только конструкция `do {...} while ();`

Comment: если так уж трудно do-while поставьте просто `while (true) {}`

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно помогло, но только после выполнения действия у меня консоль закрывается от нажатия на любую кнопку, как мне сделать так, чтобы я мог вводить числа до бесконечности, например
5+5=10
и на следующей строчки я смог заново ввести любое число и чтобы программа так же выполнило действие
(5+5=10
10+20=30)
И потом, когда мне вздумается, я ввожу exit и программа закроется

Answer (score 2):

Ну вынесите проверку в `while` - типа

```
do {
    ...
    cin >> o;
} while (o != "exit");
exit(0);   // Если это в функции main(), то можно просто выйти из нее
```

Примерно так...